# The WOT on the unit ball of $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ is determined by total subsets of $\mathcal{H}$.

Tags: hilbert-spaces, operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras, weak-topology

The following picture is taken from the **Chapter 5** (page-305) of [Kadison-Ringrose I](https://bookstore.ams.org/gsm-15). In this picture the authors have described an argument of the fact that the WOT on unit ball of $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H})$ is determined by a subset of $\mathcal{H}$ whose closed linear span is equal to $\mathcal{H}$:

[image]

Here, I could not verify this last line:

> For this, note that $|\langle Ax, x \rangle|$ is small (with $A$ in $(\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H}))_1$) provided $|\langle Ay, y \rangle|$ is small with $y$ (in the span of $(x_j)$) sufficiently near $x$.

What I have done so far is as follows:

$|\langle Ax, x \rangle|=|\langle Ax-Ay, x-y \rangle- \langle Ay, y \rangle + \langle Ax, y \rangle +\langle Ay, x \rangle|\le||x-y||^2+ |\langle Ay, y \rangle|+|\langle Ax, y \rangle| +|\langle Ay, x \rangle|$

Now, $|\langle Ay, y \rangle|$ and $||x-y||$ are small but how do I manage the last two terms in this last inequality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You keep going:
$$
|\langle Ax,y\rangle|\leq|\langle A(x-y),y\rangle|+|\langle Ay,y\rangle|
\leq \|x-y\|\,\|y\|+|\langle Ay,y\rangle|. 
$$

Comment: Thank you so much